# Can't I only print one loop? - C

Tags: c, loops

I want to print three char variables with a *for* loop but I don't know why only last is printed.

This is my code:

```
int main (){

    int i, j, k;
    char word[50], old[1], new[1];

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    gets(word);

    printf("Enter desired letter to substitute: ");
    gets(old);

    printf("Enter the new letter: ");
    gets (new);

    for (i = 0; i<strlen(word); i++){
        printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j<strlen(old); j++){
        printf("%c", old[j]);
    }   
    for (k = 0; k<strlen(new); k++){
        printf("%c", new[k]);
    }
}
```

I don't get why this simply code doesn't work.

Comment: Please ensure the size of the array, including the EOS('\0')

Comment: Also, please do not use "new" as a variable name. It is a reserved keyword. You could call it newLetter to make it consistent with the text.

Comment: @NickKarnik `new` is not keyword in `C`.

Comment: When you're asking a question about a `printf` statement within a `for` loop, it's helpful to specify which one(s) is(are) problematic when your posted code has 3 instances of this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code overflows the buffers for `old` and `new` because they do not contain enough space for a 1 character string.  In C strings needs to be null terminated, so a `char` array must always be one element longer than the maximum number of characters it must contain.  For example your `word` array can only hold a 49 character string, since the 50th element must be the null.

So `old` and `new` must both be `char[2]` arrays.

Comment: This is correct, and they can also just be chars, if you only need a length 1 array anyway. That won't prevent you from substituting them in a char array.

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are unnecessary and incorrect. You can print the values directly without specifying the index. In your post you're trying to loop through each index and print a character at a time. Here's what you should do:

```
int main (){

int i, j, k;
char word[50], old[2], new[2];

printf("Enter a word: ");
gets(word);

printf("Enter desired letter to substitute: ");
gets(old);

printf("Enter the new letter: ");
gets (new);

printf("%s\n", word);
printf("%s\n", old);
printf("%s\n", new);
```

}

Comment: the output is: ¯Ýý
I use Dev-C++ 5.5.3

Comment: Oops sorry, the %c needs to be changed to %s. Also, your array buffer needs to be bigger.